# Работа с кириллическими строками в Ruby

Tags: gems, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Всем привет!

Во многих источниках пишут про кириллические строки, и использование с ними методов upcase/downcase/capitalize возможно лишь при подключении, например, гема activesupport (метод chars).

Данный код:

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_support"
s = "привет"
puts s
puts s.upcase
puts s.chars.upcase
```

По идее, должен возвращать:

```
привет
привет
ПРИВЕТ
```

Но на деле возвращает:

```
привет
привет
upper.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `upcase' for ["п", "р", "и", "в", "е", "т"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать, чтобы указанные мной выше методы работали корректно с кириллицей. Без использования гема activesupport методы работают корректно только с английским. С использованием этого гема - ошибка.

Версии: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux] /
Rails 4.1.6

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: > upper.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `upcase' for ["п", "р", "и", "в", "е", "т"]:Array (NoMethodError)

Если прочитать содержимое ошибки, то все становится понятно - `.chars` возвращает **список** символов, а у списка самого по себе нет и не может быть никакого метода upcase (т.к. в нем может быть что угодно, а не только символы).

По поводу того, что кириллица не переводится в верхний регистр: upcase, очевидно, работает на уровне ASCII, где нет кириллицы и простой математической зависимости между регистрами. Здесь описана работа с юникодом: http://toster.ru/q/10942#answers_list

Comment: @Etki, большущее спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. После таких ответов становится яснее работа "кишок" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод .mb_chars

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html

http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars

Comment: Спасибо, с данным методом работает!

Единственное, хотелось бы обозначить один интересный момент (для тех, кто будет искать ответ на мой изначальный вопрос).

Гем необходимо подгружать обязательно в таком виде:
require "active_support/all"
Ну, или, конечно же, можно выбрать только /mb_chars.

Дело в том, что при подключении гема без указателя:
require "active_support"

будем получать ошибку:
upper.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `mb_chars' for "привет":String (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Цитата:

> Гем необходимо подгружать обязательно в таком виде: `require "active_support/all"`. Ну, или, конечно же, можно выбрать только `/mb_chars`. Дело в том, что при подключении гема без указателя: `require "active_support"` будем получать ошибку: `upper.rb:10:in <main>': undefined method mb_chars' for "привет":String (NoMethodError)`

Я подключал метод mb_chars следующим образом:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'
```

Его определение находится в файле `../string/multibyte.rb`

Плюс еще можно перекодировать вводимые с консоли винды строки в utf-8:

```
Your_Users_String = gets.chomp
Your_Users_String.encode!("utf-8")
```

После этого строковые методы с `mb_chars` работают, по крайней мере у меня.

Comment: Когда вы редактируете сообщение, внизу можно увидеть на предварительном просмотре, что получится.